# Adding specific version of scala-xml in fat jar

Tags: java, xml, scala, sbt-assembly

I would like to use the scala-xml jar with my project, I have the following configuration for the fat jar.

In **[a previous project](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/scalaexercises/blob/master/project/Dependencies.scala)**, I was able to use **[XML locally](https://github.com/vamsiampolu/scalaexercises/blob/master/src/test/scala/example/XmlSpec.scala)** using the version:

```
lazy val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang" % "scala-xml" % "2.11.0-M4"
```

but when I try and use that version with my fat jar, I get the error from my deployed jar( however, my tests still run correctly on my local machine):

```
scala/Product$class: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
at scala.xml.NamespaceBinding.<init>(NamespaceBinding.scala:23)
at scala.xml.TopScope$.<init>(TopScope.scala:17)
at scala.xml.TopScope$.<clinit>(TopScope.scala)
at example.models.soap11.SoapEnvelope$.toXML(SoapEnvelope.scala:9)
at example.AWSLambdaRequestHandler.execute(RequestHandler.scala:73)
```

**scala-xml** related

```
lazy val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
```

**Error(tl;dr)**

```
org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12: not found
```

I have gone through this **[issue](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/issues/79)** where the solution recommended was to do **sbt update** but that did not resolve my issue. Instead it resulted in the Error message above.

The **build.sbt** file of the project **[here](https://github.com/scala/scala-xml/blob/master/build.sbt)** seems to use

```
libraryDependencies += ("org.scala-lang" % "scala-compiler" % scalaVersion.value % "test").exclude("org.scala-lang.modules", s"scala-xml_${scalaVersion.value}")
```

as a test dependency. There are 2 other versions defined there:

```
version := "1.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
mimaPreviousVersion := Some("1.0.6"),
```

I have also tried the following configurations:

```
lazy val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang.modules" % "scala-xml_2.12" % "1.0.6"
lazy val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml_2.12" % "1.0.6"
lazy val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"
```

---

Detailed config and Error message:

**build.sbt(Entire file)**

```
import sbt.Keys.{libraryDependencies, _}
import sbt._

val lambdaVersion = "1.2.0"
val awsVersion = "1.11.22"

val json4sVersion = "3.6.0-M2"
val sttpVersion = "1.1.1"

lazy val scalaXml = "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "1.0.6"

lazy val sttp = Seq(
  "com.softwaremill.sttp" %% "core",
  "com.softwaremill.sttp" %% "json4s"
).map(_ % sttpVersion)

lazy val json4s = Seq(
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-ext"
).map(_ % json4sVersion)

lazy val awsLambda = Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core"
).map(_ % lambdaVersion)

lazy val aws = Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-s3"
).map (_ % awsVersion)


javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
      retrieveManaged := true
    )),
    name := "aws-scala-lambda-test",
    libraryDependencies += scalaXml,
    libraryDependencies ++= json4s,
    libraryDependencies ++= awsLambda,
    libraryDependencies ++= aws,
    libraryDependencies ++= sttp,
    libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.3" % Test,
    libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test
)

assemblyJarName in assembly := "my-example.jar"
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", _ @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case _ => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

**Error**

```
$ sbt
> update
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/localuser/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12/scala-reflect-2.12.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/localuser/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/localuser/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-lang/scala-reflect/2.12/scala-reflect-2.12.pom
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang.modules#scala-parser-combinators_2.12;1.0.4 ...
[info] Resolving org.mockito#mockito-all;1.10.19 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/localuser/.ivy2/local/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12/scala-compiler-2.12.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/localuser/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/localuser/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-lang/scala-compiler/2.12/scala-compiler-2.12.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.12: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.12: not found
[warn]  :: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.12: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
```

Comment: Maybe you meant "2.12.4" instead of "2.12"?

Comment: Yeah `scalaVersion` is wrong.  Running `update` in sbt with the `build.sbt` as it is fails.